# Prove the correctness algorithm for computing the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Prove correctness of the following algorithm for computing the $n$th Fibonacci number.

**algorithm** fastfib (integer $n$)
**if** $n \lt 0$ **return** $0$;
**else if** $n = 0$ **return** $0$;
**else if** $n = 1$ **return** $1$;
**else** $a \leftarrow 1; b \leftarrow 0$;
$\qquad$**for** $i$ from $2$ to $n$ **do**
$\qquad$$\qquad$ $t \leftarrow a; a \leftarrow a + b; b \leftarrow t$;
**return** $a$;
**end**

Can anyone show me how to prove the correctness of this algorithm? It seems like a code

Comment: *It seems like a code*. Well, it is a code !

Comment: Well, if you insist that Fibonacci numbers with negative index are $0$ (generally, that's not done, it's extended in such a way that the recurrence is still valid for negative indices), it seems to be correct. I'd call it slowfib, though. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the code is correct.

You can proceed by induction, say the code worked for all natural numbers $1,2,3\dots ,n$.

Then when you input $n+1$ then the for loop, runs from $2$ to $n+1$, we know that when inside the for loop we reach $i=n-1$, we have $a=F_{n-1}$, the $(n-1)$th fibonacci number, as the code worked fine when your input was $n-1$.

So after that when we have $i=n$, then we have $b=F_{n-1}$(from the above argument) and  $a=F_{n}$ as the code worked fine when your input was $n$, so when $i=n+1$, $a=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$, so you are given the right output, hence your code is perfectly ok!

Answer (score 0):

Case $n>1$:
Can you prove by recurrence that for each i from 2 to n,

$t_i=F_{i-1}, a_i=F_i, b_i=F_{i-1}$ ?